# Instantiating View Controller from code - When is viewDidLoad called iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am using something like:
`VC = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

viewDidLoad is not called yet.
But when I do:
`VC.view.frame = CGRectMake(...);`

At this point viewDidLoad is called.

But the issue is, that the view dimensions that I am passing in the above code statement is not used in the `viewDidLoad` method.
I think it sees that view is being used, so it is time to load the view, and after loading the view it must be assigning the frame dimensions to the view. But what if I want that view dimensions set before `viewDidLoad` gets called, so that I can use those dimensions in the `viewDidLoad` method..
Something like `initWithFrame..`

Also, I don't have the view dimensions in the view controller. I have to assign the view dimensions from outside of the VC.
So probably after calling `initWithNibName:bundle:` method I can save the view frame dimensions in some variable.. but that doesn't look like a clean solution, does it?

Comment: In your SettingsViewController you could create a new init method which takes a CGRECT object.

Comment: @JDx oh yeah! ofcourse that should work

Comment: Even then, viewDidLoad will not have the new dimensions. Whenever i'll try to assign new dimensions, it will first load the view and then assign dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

In the interface

```
@interface SettingsViewController : ... {
    CGRect _initialFrame;
}

...

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@end
```

In the implementation

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        _initialFrame = frame;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.frame = _initialFrame;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

and then from the class you use these controller:

```
VC = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I mentioned, and that seems the best way out.

Answer (score 3):

`viewDidLoad` is called when the view did load. (surprise)

so by the time you call `VC.view`, before it return, the `viewDidLoaded` will be executed and then the view is returned, and set the frame.

so from your current approach, it is not possible

anyway, why you need view frame in `viewDidLoad`? maybe you can move that part into `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidAppear` which is only get called when the view is about to present

Comment: Currently I am doing that only

Comment: @neeraj doing what? is any reason that you must know view frame in `viewDidLoad` and cannot move these code to `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidAppear`

Comment: I have already moved them there. I was just curious. Maybe someday I want to do something just once, and not every time the view appears or disappears, then I'll have to keep a seaprate flag for that purpose